# Windows Server 2012 R2 Local Policy Editor is missing System Services?

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, gpedit

I'm using `gpedit.msc` to edit the local security policy on a Windows Server 2012 R2 box and I want to set a service to diabled. I know I could just do this in `services.msc` but I want it done in policy so I can export it and use it on other servers.

Google points me to a bunch of screenshots and posts saying it should be under `Local Computer Policy/Computer Configuration/Windows Settings/Security Settings/System Services` but `System Services` is nowhere to be found on my system; It's completely missing.

How do I get this section back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the `System Services` is simply just not there on local policy for Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2, and can only be accessed from GPM on an AD server. Why Microsoft left this out is beyond me.